# How to do a summation only within specific cells via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, target

In reference to the picture below, I would like to loop through a certain column (Column D in this case) until I hit a specific cell (Yellow cells in this case). In my final spreadsheet I have multiple yellow cells that I would like to target. Once I hit a yellow cell, I would like to start a simple summation of the values one cell to the left of the yellow (Column C). I would like to keep summing the values until I hit a blank cell, which would indicate the end of the set.

[image]

Please let me know if you need any more clarification!

Comment: Do you want the *Sum()* to run from **C1** to the found row or from the previous found row to the new found row ??

Comment: Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it. If you don't know where to start, try using the Macro Recorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that should get the job done. However you are going to have to adapt it to however you want to use it.

```
Dim Summation as Double
For Each Target in Range("D:D")
    If Target.Interior.ColorValue = 6 Then
        Summation = Summation + Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
    End If
Next Target
```

I hope this helps. However, don't forget about FreeMan's suggestions about good question asking and using the macro recorder!